# Way to manipulate strings in UTF8 in Java (rather than converting to UTF16)?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I've an application where I receive a lot of strings as messages, as byte arrays in which there's a UTF-8 string. The application merely writes them in a HTTP request to another service, without caring about the content at all.

I wanted to know if there was a way to avoid the conversion to UTF-16 as it seems to me an unnecessary waste of memory and time, slowing down the application.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to avoid any conversion: by not converting it. What is the code, why do you currently convert it in the first place?

Comment: No recommendations ... because that's off-topic.  But try googling for "UTF8string java" ....

Comment: Java is smarter than you think. Newer versions of Java do not always automatically convert characters to 2 bytes in memory. See [Compact Strings in Java 9](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string) and [JEP 254: Compact Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254).

Comment: While it may make sense, it's nigh impossible if you need to work with `Strings` unless on Java 9>=  like Jesper said. Routing the data as bytes OTOH would provide additional complexity. At least don't start by assuming you've found an essential performance hotspot. Dozens of applications have managed just fine with UTF-16 internal representation, so maybe yours isn't that special either?

Comment: Even in Java 9+, regardless of whether a `String` *internally* stores UTF-16 or Latin1 or whatever in memory, the *public interface* for interacting with the `String` is UTF-16 only, so there will be conversions one way or the other.  So, if you have UTF-8 byes, and you want to keep it UTF-8 and process it as UTF-8, then you have to deal with the raw bytes, not convert the bytes to `String` at all.